# hierarchy structure xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Need to draw a hierarchy like below image

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want xamarin.form layout like this. Or any idea how I can implement this.

Comment: first of all, your question seems that you had no effort searching for a solution whatsoever, at least provide some background info or atleast what you have tried so far, for future reference, try not to ask questions like "i want to do this, tell me how", despite that, i would advice you to use a Grid layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use a [**Grid**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) to achive the layout on the image.

here is an example how to use a Grid to achive the desired hierarchy:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    //TOP
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="image_top" />
    </StackLayout>

    //CENTER
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="image_center_left" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="image_center_right" />
    </StackLayout>

    //BOTTOM
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="image_bottom_far_left" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="image_bottom_left" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="image_bottom_right" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="image_bottom_far_right" />
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

**Note**: if you want to use the lines connecting the hierarchy (assuming that they are images), you will need to add 2 extra rows and add them between the images rows.

Comment: a very good explanation this is what I needed. can you help me with a line? like how can I draw a line? @Ricardo Dias Morais

Comment: @abhi if that is what you need, be sure to mark it as the correct anwser, about the lines, you can either use a boxview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/boxview, with an height of 2/3, and that way you can simulate a line, or you can use an image too, but it might get strectch if it width is dynamic